# Query/retrieve Neo4j metrics

Tags: neo4j, cypher

From Neo4j [operations manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/metrics/reference/#causal-clustering-metrics) I have seen that Neo4j servers/clusters report a variety of monitoring metrics.

What I don't know is *how* to query these metrics. How can I retrieve this information from a Cypher query (from the `cypher-shell`) or the HTTP interface of the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those metrics are dump into a CSV file or directly send to Ganglia if the connector is set.

If you want to have acces to some metric in `Cypher` or `HTTP`, I recommend you to take a look at the JMX Metrics (you will find the same things).
This is the link to the available metrics : https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.3/jmx-metrics/#jmx-mxbeans

In `Cypher` there is procedure to retrieve some JMX values :

```
CALL dbms.queryJmx('*:*')
```

And you can do the same in HTTP :

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:7474/db/manage/server/jmx/domain/*/*
```

Comment: How can I get only one single metric? say: `neo4j.causal_clustering.core.commit_index`?